# Using strpos to search a string for a date

Tags: php, strpos

I have been trying (and searching, and searching) for a way to search an XML feed using today's date. I have had success when manually inputting a date, but I'd like to be able to automate it.

Here's the PHP I started with:

```
if(strpos($record, "2014-01-03") !== false) {
```

That worked, and wasn't too much of a pain as I was changing it once a week.

Soon, I needed to change the date daily, so I figured I would try:

```
if(strpos($record, (date("Y-m-d"))) !== false) {
```

But that is not working.

Does anyone have any solutions using `strpos`, or is there something else I should be using?

Here is some of what's in the `$record`

```
2014-01-03T13:09:08-08:00
2014-01-02T18:27:59-08:00
2013-12-21T14:59:19-08:00
2013-12-21T14:58:48-08:00
2013-12-20T19:54:57-08:00
2013-12-20T19:49:39-08:00
2013-12-20T19:44:02-08:00
2013-12-20T19:36:00-08:00
2013-12-20T19:13:24-08:00
2013-12-20T19:04:42-08:00
2013-12-20T17:35:35-08:00
2013-12-20T15:45:13-08:00
2013-12-20T13:44:58-08:00
2013-12-19T20:30:45-08:00
2013-12-19T19:20:24-08:00
2013-12-19T17:58:31-08:00
2013-12-18T19:28:18-08:00
2013-12-18T18:01:01-08:00
2013-12-17T18:32:19-08:00
2013-12-16T18:57:40-08:00
2013-12-16T17:05:45-08:00
2013-12-14T20:39:22-08:00
```

I'm trying to use that to display each day's given data.

Comment: Seems like it should work, maybe give us more code, or the data in $record?

Comment: Sure thing. Appreciate your help. Editing my question.

Comment: Seems to be working fine with your code and data: https://eval.in/85733

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. Is it possible, then, that it does not work with the specific XML parser I'm using? I'm using [MagicParser](http://www.magicparser.com/).

Comment: Updated since the date changed, so I updated the data.... https://eval.in/85749 I would var_dump($record) and make sure it's what you think it is.

Comment: A-ha! Thank you so much for your help. Your code pushed to further dig into this before I finally realized it was a timezone issue. I used `strtotime` as a quick way to change the time, and my data is now returning as I had hoped. Thanks again!